# Memcached with Spring

Tags: java, spring, caching, memcached

I have a Spring based application that uses Spring core, Spring MVC and Spring Data (Mongo) on the server side, and designed as a typical 3-tier application.

I have a list of services, that are typical Spring services/beans that I wish you integrate with memcached to cache some of my service results.

Can someone guide me to the steps to integrate memcached with spring for such an application?
A sample/tutorial/blog that gives a step by step process would be just great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Spring 3.1 take a look at [Spring Cache](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html) abstraction. It's the easiest way to integrate caching in Spring application. Unfortunately Spring doesn't support memcached out of the box, there's only support for ehcache.

As far as I know there isn't available any provider that can store data to memcached through Spring Cache. In few days next version 3.0.0 of [Simple Spring Memcached](http://code.google.com/p/simple-spring-memcached/) is going to be released with such support. In mean time you may try one of the latest snapshot or use Simple Spring Memcached 2.0.0 directly without Spring Cache abstraction.

**UPDATE**: Simple Spring Memcached 3.0.0 with Spring Cache integration is already available.

Comment: i want to use memcache in spring mvc. what is this error: "No qualifying bean of type [com.google.code.ssm.Settings] is defined"

Comment: Don't worry about it, it's only an information not an error. If no custom Settings bean is defined a default values are used.

Answer (score 0):

It's very trivial to do. You can look at **3levelmemcache** project as an example at **github** its Spring based abstraction.